# 'attempt to convert incompatible units' error on HealthKit Statistics query (swift)

Tags: swift, healthkit

I am needing to calculate the cumulative sum of calories, and am getting the error 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to convert incompatible units: kcal, count'

on the line:

```
let numberOfCalories = Int(sumQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.caloriesUnit))
```

My unit has been defined as:

```
let caloriesUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
```

Should it be something different? How can I return the number of calories?

my function is:

```
func queryCaloriesSum() {

    let caloriesQuantityType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned) //else //{ return nil }

    let sumOption = HKStatisticsOptions.CumulativeSum
    let statisticsSumQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: caloriesQuantityType!, quantitySamplePredicate: nil, options: sumOption) { [unowned self] (query, result, error) in
        if let sumQuantity = result?.sumQuantity() {

           // let headerView = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.totalStepsCellIdentifier)! as UITableViewCell

            let numberOfCalories = Int(sumQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.caloriesUnit))

        print(numberOfCalories)
        }

    }
    healthStore.executeQuery(statisticsSumQuery)
    print(statisticsSumQuery)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My unit has been defined as:
>
> ```
> let caloriesUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
> ```
>
> Should it be something different? How can I return the number of calories?

How about using [`calories`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkunit/1615359-calorie) for calories?

Comment: It brings the same error. That was just changing the label, it made no difference to the code, to my knowledge. I tried 'let calories = HKUnit.countUnit()'. No luck. Thank you though - I am a beginner, so perhaps I misunderstood your tip?

Comment: PS I also tried adding 'class func calorie() -> Self' to the top of the page. But that didn't work. Where should I note that declaration?

Comment: @DimitriT, **you did what?** You should just change `let caloriesUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()` to  `let caloriesUnit = HKUnit.calorieUnit()` or `let caloriesUnit = HKUnit.kilocalorieUnit()`.